# How to create kentico site specific resource strings in each sites?

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

In my site they have configured in 5 sites. SiteName: A,B,C,D,E.

I want to have the ability to customise these two pieces of text by site using a site specific resource (localization) string for each text field.

These resource strings should be configurable by an Admin on Kentico, and should be able to be configured by each site.

The current names of these strings in Kentico are “A.Checkout.EmailTitle” and “A.Checkout.EmailDescription” for the Title and Description respectively.

I using below code:

public string GetPerSiteResourceString(string name, string site = "")

```
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(site))

        {
            site = SiteContext.CurrentSiteName;
        }
        var fullname = $"{site}.{name}";

        var perSiteStringInfo = ResourceStringInfoProvider.GetResourceStringInfo(fullname, LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode);
        if (perSiteStringInfo != null && perSiteStringInfo.StringID > 0)
        {
            return perSiteStringInfo.TranslationText;
        }
        return ResHelper.GetString(name, LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode);
    }
```

Title = resources.GetPerSiteResourceString("Kadena.Checkout.EmailTitle"),
                Description = resources.GetPerSiteResourceString("Kadena.Checkout.EmailDescription")

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on [your question on the Kentico DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-to-create-kentico-site-specific-resource-strings-in-each-sites), Kentico is NOT set up to handle this out of the box.

However, the approach you outlined would work for retrieving the data but there is no way to limit who has access to edit what unless you modify the Kentico UI and/or create new Localization listing pages for each site.

If you were to create a new module, then create new pages only accessible by individual site users, you may be able to set the WHERE condition to look at the beginning of the key string and compare it to the current site.